# Letting $\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

I know this is minor, but how is it that you justify this formally?

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
| x - a | < \delta &\Rightarrow |f(x) - l| < \epsilon \\
&\Rightarrow |f(x) - l| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

To better illustrate what I mean, consider as a counter-example how easy it is to justify something like this:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
| x - a | < \delta &\Rightarrow |f(x) - l| < \epsilon \\
&\Rightarrow|f(x) - l| < 3\epsilon
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Comment: Usually, $\epsilon - \delta$ definitions require that they should hold for all values of $\epsilon$. The new $\epsilon$ is not the same as old one.

Comment: There is no justification for $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |f(x) - l| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. The most likely possibilities are that you misread something (that is, the implication you wrote is not what the text said), or someone simply made a mistake (for example, forgetting that one of the symbols needed a subscript to distinguish it from the other). If you want an explanation for what you saw I think you'll have to give us more of the context.

Comment: No, I didn't misread it. I think Exp ikx got it right, and the textbook just lets $\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ without making explicit that it is a new epsilon.

Comment: @user_hello1 Fine, but even as such, the first part of your question, as written, is undoubtedly wrong, and any author who writes this is sloppy at best.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. From my perspective, this isn't an unreasonable question to ask when it comes to limits. I thought when I first learned about the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition of limits, as well as the OP, that being able to use things like $\epsilon/2$ to bound $|f(x) - l|$ was an implication from the definition of limit, and have done my best to clarify this as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you're talking about this in the context of limits.

Let's suppose you **know** for a fact that $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L\text{.} \tag{*}$$

By definition, this means that **for every** $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

The **for every** part is key.

**If we know that (*) holds** (this assumption is important), we could say that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ (let's assume we don't care about the actual value of $\delta$) such that if $|x - a| < \delta$, $|f(x) - L| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Why? Because since we're assuming $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive number, $\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ is an arbitrary positive number as well, no matter what $\epsilon > 0$ is!

The long story short is that you can stick anything in that inequality in place of $\epsilon$ **as long as the limit exists** (i.e,. (*) holds) and as long as what you have there is an arbitrary positive number!

To answer your question directly (and this has been addressed in the comments), the following is **FALSE**:

$$|x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon \nRightarrow |f(x) - L| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}\text{.}$$

What you *can* say is the following: suppose $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L$. (**Notice how I have this assumption available to me.**) Then, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Of course for a fixed $\epsilon, \delta$, the following is false:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
| x - a | < \delta &\Rightarrow |f(x) - l| < \epsilon \\
&\Rightarrow |f(x) - l| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$
But these are equivalent:
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0\big[| x - a | < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - l| < \epsilon\big]
$$
and
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0\; \exists \delta > 0\big[| x - a | < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - l| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}\big]
$$

Answer (score 1):

The statement as you've written it is false, but there is a way to work this.

I assume this is in the context of analysis, working with the ever-present definition of a limit: $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. The thing to note here is that the $\delta$ that exists depends on the originally chosen $\epsilon$, so we can imagine it as a function $\delta(\epsilon)$ picking a suitable $\delta$ for each input $\epsilon$.

For every $\epsilon$ we have $|x-a|<\delta(\epsilon) \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Therefore for every epsilon we have $|x-a|<\delta(\frac{\epsilon}{2}) \implies |f(x) - L| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$